# Не работает pyautogui.size() и pyautogui.position()

Tags: python

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
import time
import keyboard

pyautogui.size()
pyautogui.position()
```

Не выдаёт разрешения экрана и позицию курсора.

Пишу в Sublime Text 4 и при нажатие на запуск кода(ctrl + b) код просто завершается.

Так же пробовал запускать через cmd но тоже код просто завершается.

Модуль pyautogui скачивал.

Comment: print(pyautogui.size())
print(pyautogui.position())
input("Для продолжения нажмите Enter...") Вставьте это, отформатируйте. Не выводит не чего потому что нужно выводить на печать при помощи функции print() <!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import os

In [2]: import pyautogui

In [3]: print(pyautogui.position())
Point(x=832, y=118)

In [4]: print(pyautogui.size())
Size(width=1440, height=900)

In [5]: os.system("pause")
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```